# specify(distinguish) .c and .h file icon in file explorer and they opened with vscode

Tags: windows, file, visual-studio-code, icons

in Win10, my *file.c* and *file.h* are open with VSCODE

then the c-file and h-file icon both look like

"[c]header.h" and "[c]main.c"
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1ny1.jpg)

I want them look like
"[h]header.h" and [c]main.c

Answer (score 1):

I found one solution myself:

I used
https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/12383/change-a-file-types-icon-in-windows-7/
to get and change the icon

used
https://redketchup.io/icon-editor
to edit the icon file

now they look like: [sreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHrNZ.jpg)